# OCMockObject mocking an instance method

Tags: ios, ocmock, xctest

I am new to OCMockObjects and trying to mock an instance method of ACAccount class:

```
-(NSArray *)accountsWithAccountType:(ACAccountType *)accountType;
```

I wrote this code in the test class to intialize mockObject:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
id mockAccountStore = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:accountStore];
[[[mockAccountStore stub] andReturn:@[@"someArray"]] accountsWithAccountType:[OCMArg any]];

//call the test method
[myClassInstance methodToTest];
```

In myClass the methodToTest looks like this:

```
 -(void) methodToTest
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType* accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSArray* expectedArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
   //Getting nil value to Array rather than the returned value in stub
}
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a mock, but the method you are testing is not using the mock, it's using an instance of the original ACAccountStore class.

If you are willing, the easiest way to make `methodToTest` testable is to have it accept an instance of ACAccountStore as an argument.

```
- (void)methodToTestWithAccountStore:(ACAccountStore *)accountStore;
```

Then your test looks like this:

```
[myClassInstance methodToTest:mockAccountStore];
```

This would follow a dependency injection pattern. If you don't like this pattern, you *could* mock the `alloc` method of ACAccountStore to return your mock object, but I am always wary of possible side-effects from mocking `alloc` and instead would suggest creating a factory for ACAccountStore:

```
@interface ACAccountStore (Factory)
+ (instancetype)accountStore;
@end
@implementation ACAccountStore
+ (instancetype)accountStore { return [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]; }
@end
```

If you use this pattern, you can mock your factory method.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Flynn is correct that you need a way to inject an `AccountStore` into the object you're testing. Two additional ways to do this:

1) Make `accountStore` a property of the class under test that gets set at initialization, then override that property with a mock in your test.

2) Create a method like `-(ACAccountStore *)accountStore` that initializes the account store, but in your test mock that method:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
id mockAccountStore = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:accountStore];
[[[mockAccountStore stub] andReturn:@[@"someArray"]] accountsWithAccountType:[OCMArg any]];

id mockInstance = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:myClassInstance];
[[[mockInstance stub] andReturn:mockAccountStore] accountStore];

// call the test method
[myClassInstance methodToTest];
```

Comment: I like this idea, though it does mean you are expanding the scope the ACAccountStore object. Not a huge deal, though.

Comment: Yeah, I think the second approach is basically equivalent to OP's original code--it just moves the initialization into a method you can intercept at test time.